# Converting Arduino Uno with Ethernet Shield sketch for Arduino Yún

Tags: arduino-yun

I'm new to the Arduino Yun and I'm trying to convert a sketch written for the Arduino Uno with a Ethernet Shield. The sketch does HTTP posts to Azure Mobile Services.

I've added in the `Bridge.h` and `YunClient.h` libraries in place of the `Ethernet.h` one for the Uno.

My modified sketch compiles, however, I don't think the http posts are working. I don't see my table updating in Azure.

    /*
    ** This sample Arduino sketch uploads telemetry data to Azure Mobile Services
    ** See the full article here: http://hypernephelist.com/2014/07/11/arduino-uno-azure-mobile-services.html
    **
    ** Thomas Conté @tomconte
    */

```cpp
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <YunClient.h>
//#include <Ethernet.h> // removed as not used by Yun
#include <SPI.h>

// not sure if these libraries are required?
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <Process.h>

// Ethernet shield MAC address (sticker in the back)
//byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// 90:A2:DA:F8:28:38

// Azure Mobile Service address
// You can find this in your service dashboard
const char *server = "myhost.azure-mobile.net";

// Azure Mobile Service table name
// The name of the table you created
const char *table_name = "my_data";

// Azure Mobile Service Application Key
// You can find this key in the 'Manage Keys' menu on the dashboard
const char *ams_key = "HJRxFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNQoMcXXXXXXx99";

//EthernetClient client;
YunClient client;

char buffer[64];

/*
** Send an HTTP POST request to the Azure Mobile Service data API
*/

void send_request(int value)
{
  Serial.println("\nconnecting...");

    Serial.print("sending ");
    Serial.println(value);

    // POST URI
    sprintf(buffer, "POST /tables/%s HTTP/1.1", table_name);
    client.println(buffer);

    // Host header
    sprintf(buffer, "Host: %s", server);
    client.println(buffer);

    // Azure Mobile Services application key
    sprintf(buffer, "X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: %s", ams_key);
    client.println(buffer);

    // JSON content type
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");

    // POST body
    sprintf(buffer, "{\"value\": %d}", value);

    // Content length
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(strlen(buffer));

    // End of headers
    client.println();

    // Request body
    client.println(buffer);

}

/*
** Wait for response
*/

void wait_response()
{
  while (!client.available()) {
    if (!client.connected()) {
      return;
    }
  }
}


/*
** Read the response and dump to serial
*/

void read_response()
{
  bool print = true;

  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    // Print only until the first carriage return
    if (c == '\n')
      print = false;
    if (print)
      Serial.print(c);
  }
}

/*
** Close the connection
*/

void end_request()
{
  client.stop();
}

/*
** Arduino Setup
*/

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Starting Bridge");
Bridge.begin();

}

/*
** Arduino Loop
*/

void loop()
{
  int val = analogRead(A0);

  send_request(val);
  wait_response();
  read_response();
  end_request();

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Ok I figured this one out, I was missing the code to connect to the web service

if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

Comment: So? What happen? What do you did?

Answer (score 1):

(Updating answer from comments.)

The OP answered their own question, they missed the code to connect to the web service

`if (client.connect(server, 80))`